# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre llamar a funcion() y llamar a new funcion()?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este codigo

```
function DoPlayer() {

  this.name = name;
  this.number = function() {
    prompt('Ingresa un numero', "");
  };

}
```

Quisiera entender la diferencia entre llamar a la función `DoPlayer()` y hacer `new DoPlayer()`.

Comment: Porque no hay una función que se llame neww(). Por cierto, la pregunta no muestra lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el tema.

Comment: está editado me gustaria saber lo que sucede :)

Comment: Intenta usar `<input type="button" onclick="neww.number()"/>` debe funcionar

Comment: vee mi edición :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new funcion()` crea un nuevo objeto y llama a `funcion` estableciendo que ese nuevo objeto sea el valor de `this` para la funcion. (asi `funcion` hace el rol de *constructor*/te permite manipular `this`). Ademas, `new funcion()` retorna dicho objeto de forma que puedas utlizarlo luego, que cumple el rol de *instancia* del objeto.

Cuando invocas a `funcion()` directamente, el valor de `this` depende del contexto. Si la funcion la invocas desde el ambito global (ej. directo desde un tag `<script>`), entonces `this` lleva el valor de  `window`. Sino utiliza el `this` del contexto actual.

Ejemplo:

```js
function funcion() {
  
  console.log(this === window);
  
  this.otraFuncion = function() {
    console.log(this === window);
  }
  
}

// invocas a funcion, this es window.
funcion(); // true

// this es un nuevo objeto creado para tal fin.
var instancia = new funcion(); // false

// this es window
window.otraFuncion(); // true

// this es la instancia
instancia.otraFuncion(); // false
```

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que el valor de `this` **depende de quien invoca a la funcion y no de donde esta declarada**.

Este es un ejemplo concreto: la funcion `setTimeout` invoca el *callback* desde el contexto de `window`. Por lo tanto el valor de this dentro del callback es `window`.

Ejemplo:

```js
function funcion() {
  console.log( this === window );
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Aqui se aprecia que this depende de quien invoca y no del lugar donde una funcion esta declarada.
    console.log( this === window );
  }, 0);

}

funcion(); // true true
new funcion(); // false true
```

Salu2.

Comment: y entonces.. cuando hago DoPlayer() , no pasa nada?

Comment: si pasa, se crea la funcion `number` y se asigna el valor de `name`. Pero son dos funciones diferentes. una dentro de la otra. No entiendo que quieres hacer... explicame un poco

Comment: entender la diferencia entre llamar a la función DoPlayer() y hacer new DoPlayer()

Comment: @EduardoSebastian ahora entiendo. Dame unos minutos que voy a editar la respuesta (y un poco la pregunta para que tenga sentido)

Comment: @EduardoSebastian edite.